# visual basic text box to list box

Tags: vb.net, vba, textbox, listbox

I have made 2 form in my project. But I want to make the first form to enter an input and as the second form, it can display the output. The problem is, I have enter all the input using the textbox, but the output cannot be displayed in the second form by using the listbox.

Comment: can you show us the code that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Public Method on your second Form and Call it from your First Form.
I created two Forms one with a TextBox and another with a ListBox, if you want anymore detail you will need to give an example of what the problem that you are having is.

**Form1**

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim frm2 As Form2
    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        Dim tb As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
        If e.KeyChar = vbCr Then
            If tb.Text.Length > 0 Then
                frm2.ListBoxAdd(tb.Text)
                tb.Text = ""
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()
        frm2 = New Form2
        frm2.Show(Me)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Form2**

```
Public Class Form2
    Public Sub ListBoxAdd(data As String)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(data)
    End Sub
End Class
```